# Sox Is Throwing A Random Error: Option A Isn't Recognized

Tags: linux, unix, sox

I am running this command:

```
sox -t mp3 $(ls -1 /home/pi/Desktop/Music/*.mp3|sort -R) -t wav -r 44100 - | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 104.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

This is the result:

```
sox WARN getopt: option `A' not recognized
sox FAIL sox: invalid option
```

When I was running this command sox worked fine:

```
sox -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/Music/*.mp3 -t wav -r 44100 - | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 104.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

The new command is to have sox shuffle through the files in a directory randomly, but its giving me this wierd error. How can I make it work? I've done tons of research, but I can't find anything about 'option A' anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the whitespace in file names - all I had to do was change, for example, 'dasa berta.mp3' to 'dasaberta.mp3'. One of the file names had 'A' in it, and the terminal took it as a separate command. It wasn't a sox problem, it was a me-using-terminal-problem.